# How can I merge two Doctrine records without null values overwriting existing values?

Tags: php, merge, doctrine

I have an array of default values that I'd like to merge with a Doctrine record. I tried using Doctrine's merge method but it's overwriting existing values with the merge array, even if the merge array contains null values. I'd like to merge in a way that only null or empty values are replaced with existing default values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $yourRecord = new YourRecordModel();
    $yourRecord->assignIdentifier(123); // ID of the record to update
    foreach ($yourArray as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (!empty($value))
        {
            $yourRecord[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $yourRecord->save();
```

Comment: And if you are not creating a new record, you can try setting the default value for the given key (property) using this: $yourRecord->getTable()->getDefaultValueOf($key);